# module magento 1.x smtp for microsoft exchange

Tags: magento-1.7, module, smtp

We are looking for a module for magento 1.7 who can manage SMtp for a microsoft exchange mail.

Do you know a module for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get module suggestions, please use this:

https://community.magento.com/t5/Find-an-Extension-that/bd-p/find-extension